# Frobenius norm inequality alternative proof

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces

Is there any direct and "natural" way to show this property of Frobenius norm : Let $A,B \in \mathbb R^{n \times n}$ $$\lVert AB \rVert _F \leq \lVert A \rVert _F \lVert B \rVert _F$$
I started by doing the following : $$\lVert AB \rVert _F =\sqrt{\sum_{ij}(AB)_{ij}^2}=\sqrt{\sum_{ij}\big(\sum_{k=1}^nA_{ik}B_{kj}\big)^2} $$
I feel like I can/must use Cauchy-Schwarz inequality somewhere but I am stuck here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you use Cauchy-Schwarz at the only place where it makes sense:
\begin{align}
\lVert AB \rVert _F^2 &={\sum_{ij}|(AB)_{ij}|^2}={\sum_{ij}\bigg|\sum_{k=1}^nA_{ik}B_{kj}\bigg|^2}\\[0.3cm]
&\leq{\sum_{ij}\sum_{k=1}^n|A_{ik}|^2\sum_{k=1}^n|B_{kj}|^2}\\[0.3cm]
&={\sum_{i}\sum_{k=1}^n|A_{ik}|^2\sum_j\sum_{k=1}^n|B_{kj}|^2}\\[0.3cm]
&={\|A\|_F^2\,\|B\|_F^2}
\end{align}

Comment: Is this proof valid if $A$ and $B$ are complex matrices ?